# c# ERROR : The modifier 'private ' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, c#-7.0, local-functions

It doesn't matter what modifier I put on the front of the function(I've tried with public, private and even protected), I always receive an error, the same error. The code is clean only after I delete the modifier and I left the function "Array()" without one. Can someone look at my code and explain to me what is happening please, I am new to c#, and also new to asking help, so please excuse every mistake I've made so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            public void Array()//nu se pune in interiorul functiei void Main (), deoarece va forma nesting, si ne va da eroare la compilare.
            {
                int[] intArray;
                intArray = new int[3];//all values will be 3


                var doubleArray = new[] { 34.23, 10.2, 23.2 };

                //var arrayElement = doubleArray[0];
                //doubleArray[1] = 5.55;

                for (var i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
                }
            }

        }



    }
}
```

I've posted the code and the image of it down below.

[In this image you can see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTQvm.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, add the actual code to your question.

Comment: @Zer0 No it doesn't at all.

Comment: @DavidG I wish I could do it , but I don't know how. When I wanted to paste the code, it only allowed html , css and javascript languages. I tried to change the language and it required me the URL adress of the place of the code, but I don't have my code on a site and I don't know if I can put it on one.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you pasting the code directly into the window, then make sure you press the "Code sample" button to format it.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on formatting posts.

Comment: @Zer0 thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a nested function, in C# these are called [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) and don't have scope. so you need to remove the access modifier, for example:

```
public static void PrintHelloWorld()
{
    string GetName()
    {
        return "world";
    }


    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {GetName()}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answear!

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a `nested method` (also called local function). 
Nested methods may not have access modifiers. They are only **accessible from within this method.**

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answear!

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your private function inside a static function.  Remove the private.

Comment: It *is* allowed in C# 7. Not my downvote btw

Comment: ok, I will adjust...

Comment: Not sure why you mention static here, it's not relevant at all. Also, you don't really explain why removing private is helpful.

Comment: I probably should be shot...

Comment: my comment stated EXACTLY what the OP was doing btw...

Comment: No need to get so defensive, I'm just saying what I think can be improved.

Answer (score -2):

Move the function out of the Main function. Also you should mark it as static and then use it as you intend. This in case you don't want a nested method as it is already answered.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answear!

Comment: That is not an answer